# Как я могу использовать CLSID(My Computer) в FileDialog(QML)?

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

Как я могу использовать CLSID(My Computer) в FileDialog(QML), вот так к примеру не работает.

```
FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Please choose a file"
    folder: "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" //Don't work!!!!
    selectFolder: true
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("You chose: " + fileDialog.fileUrl)
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Canceled")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
folder:  "file:///::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
```

Comment: выручил, большое спасибо